# Is there a way to animate the transition from text-align left to center in an input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p7gFh/

html:

```
<input id = 'box' value = 'some text'/>
```

css:

```
#box {
    text-align:left;
}
```

js:

```
$('#box').on('click', function() {
    $(this).css({'textAlign':'center'}, 500);
});
```

Right now the text just snaps to the center on click. I tried .animate() but nothing happened. Is there a way to animate a smooth transition from text-align left to center without snapping?

Comment: no, cause right, left , justify and center are not numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only real way to achieve this is through some funky behind-the-scenes magic, using a temporary element that mimics the text inside the input.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/xLg93/

```
$('#box').on('focus', function () {
    var full_width = $(this).width();
    var t = document.createElement('span');
    t.innerHTML = $(this).val();
    t.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.body.appendChild(t);
    var text_width = $(t).width();
    document.body.removeChild(t);
    $(this).animate({
        'text-indent': (full_width - text_width) / 2
    });
});
```

Keep in mind you'll have to style the temporary element's font-size, font-face and letter-spacing to be identical to the input box, otherwise it won't animate to the exact center.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I recently had the same issue and found the answer here wrong and unsatisfying.

- You **can** animate it using pure CSS(3)
- You **can even** use the hardware-accelerated `transform: translate()` technique for it

This is my solution:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.b').addClass('left');
}, 5000);
```

```css
.b {
  transform: translateX(50%);
  transition: transform ease-in-out 1000ms;
}
.c {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: green;
  transition: transform ease-in-out 1000ms;
}
.b.left,
.b.left .c {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b">
  <div class="c">CENTERED TEXT</div>
</div>
```